# What's the proper way to attach an exterior door threshold?

Tags: doors, installation, exterior, caulk, gap

I'm adding a hardwood threshold to bridge the gap between interior hardwood flooring and an exterior threshold leading out to our flat roof deck. My question(s):

- I've got the piece fitted and plan on using galvanized screws to
  attach, is that the correct way?
- Do I need to use some sort of glue or sealant underneath?
- Should I caulk the edges once I have it attached?
- Finally, there is tiny gap on the interior side due to the
  irregularity of the hardwood floor, is it fine to keep as is?

After attaching the threshold, I plan on staining and sealing it, just want to make sure I'm actually doing the attaching correctly. Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I did this just the other day after having to adjust the threshold to level the door.  I used finished nails into the floor.  There does appear to be a good bit of water damage there.  I'd try to cleanup the black parts by gently scraping it with sharp chisel.

Comment: I would use either brass wood screws or stainless steel screws (countersunk) to secure the threshold. I would use stainless steel nails in an area that can get wet.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I believe the water damage is in part due to the wooden deck that used to be out on the flat roof. We just had the flat roof redone and are foregoing the wood deck. Did you end up caulking the threshold after securing?

Comment: No, I did not use caulk on the inside trim.